# Complete and incomplete norm in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $X$ be a **plain vector space**. Since we can always equip $X$ with a norm,
>
> 1. Can we always equip $X$ with a **complete** norm?
> 2. Can we always equip $X$ with an **incomplete** norm?

Comment: Are all topological vector space equivalent to some Banach space?

Comment: Every Banach space must have finite or uncountable dimension. On the other hand if you believe that every vector space has a basis then you can also define the $\ell^1$ norm on this basis, which will however not make the space complete unless it is finite dimensional.